# Force.com IDE 36 - "Upgrade Project" unable to connect to previously working org

Tags: ide

I just upgraded my Eclipse from 35 to the latest 36. As with every update every projects asks for an Upgrade but this always fails with

[image]

Comment: Also posted as GitHub issue here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues/162

Comment: Is the organization instance also updated to API 36?

Comment: Uhhm, no...:-( I guess that is a problem. Any way to uninstall it or make it work for the next 15 days until we get the Spring '16 upgrade?

Comment: I don't think so. You'll have to wait for the update, since it is installed per instance, and not per organization. From what I have seen, some sandboxes are updated to the Spring 16 release before their production environments, but you'll need to check yours anyway. NA24, for example, has the update scheduled to the February 13th. (source: http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/instances/NA24)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also reverting back my Eclipse configuration didn't work, simply uninstalling v36 worked. After that I was able to reinstall v.35.